# cursor with AND in where clause

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-sqlite

How do I add an `AND` to my `WHERE` clause in an Android `Cursor`?

---

For example:

```
    Cursor cursor = data.query(
            Banana.URI, 
            new String[]{BananaColumns._ID}, 
            BananaColumns.NAME + "=? AND " + BananaColumns.COLLECTION + "=?", 
            new String[]{bananaData.getName(), bananaData.getCategory()}, 
            null);
```

This returns an empty `Cursor`. But the `Table` contains data that should be found by that query. Is my formatting wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The query looks fine to me if you want: `SELECT _id FROM BananaTable WHERE name=<bananaData.getName()> AND collection=<bananaData.getCategory()>`. (I made a few assumptions on the names.) Double check that the bananaData methods return what you expect.

Comment: It does. I stepped through it already. I even did a manual sql query with the same data and it worked fine. Going to step through it a couple more times and see if i missed anything.

Comment: ...Frustrating. Would you post the manual query?

Comment: I suspect some special characters coming in. Could you test with hardcoded values and see?

Comment: @Sam: Frustrating indeed. HOWEVER, i did find the mistake. I have two different categories... i was using the wrong category. o.O  Using the correct category gives me the expected results. Thanks for the help, and if you post your suggestions from your comment as an answer, i will be more than happy to accept it as the solution.

Comment: Glad I could help (even in a small way)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query looks fine to me if you want: `SELECT _id FROM BananaTable WHERE name=<bananaData.getName()> AND collection=<bananaData.getCategory()>`. (I made a few assumptions on the names.) Double check that the bananaData methods return what you expect.

Comment: Double checking the data returned by my `bananaData`, helped me find that i was actually using the wrong `category`. I have multiple `categories` in `bananaData`... embarrassing. o.O